# Synology task scheduler shell script not performing scp copy

Tags: shell, sh, synology

I am trying to create a task on our Synology NAS that runs every night and fetches backups from a remote server and copy it to the NAS.

This is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

WD=$(/bin/dirname $0)
Log=$WD/sync-error.log

/bin/echo "-------" >> $Log
/bin/echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d--%R): " >> $Log
/bin/echo "Clearing all backups that are older than 60 days." >> $Log

/bin/echo "Starting calenso backup" >> $Log

/bin/echo "Making sure that directory '$(date +%Y-%m-%d)' exists" >> $Log
mkdir -p /volume1/home/$(date +%Y%m%d)

/bin/echo "Start copying files from nine.ch" >> $Log
/bin/scp -r www-data@xxx.xxx.com:/home/www-data/backup/$(date +%Y%m%d)/* /volume1/home/$(date +%Y%m%d)

/bin/echo "SCP is done" >> $Log

/bin/echo "Backup is done" >> $Log
/bin/echo "-------" >> $Log
```

When I run the script manually in the Terminal, then it works perfectly. However, when its started via task scheduler, the script runs, outputs data, but the scp-command is ignored.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you try placing the source and destination in double quotes respectively in the scp command? Also the mkdir destination in double quotes?

Comment: The user of running the script manually in the Terminal is different with the task scheduler? Which way do you create the task scheduler? Like this "https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/system_taskscheduler?version=6" ? What's different log in the remote server between these two ways? Maybe something wrong with authority?

Comment: You might see if you can modify your script to capture some more debug information.  Specifically add `-vvv` to your scp and redirect that output to your $Log.   Something like:  `/bin/scp -vvv -r www-data@xxx.xxx.com:/home/www-data/backup/$(date +%Y%m%d)/* /volume1/home/$(date +%Y%m%d) 2>&1  ${Log}`

Comment: i would suggest making sure that `scp` is actually at `/bin/scp` it could be located at `/usr/bin/scp` and the error get suppressed. Also make sure that the `scp` executable on the remote side works because the problem might be caused by a problematic installation there https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236890/145533v.